# Single-statement control-flow statements in Razor documents statements cannot contain markup error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Getting the following error:

> Single-statement control-flow statements in Razor documents statements
> cannot contain markup. Markup should be enclosed in "{" and "}".

[image]

**I am building ASP.NET CORE 5 project and I get this error.** *I don't understand what error is this. Is there anyone who can help?*

Comment: The files with the errors are empty. Did you create them?

Comment: Please close your vs2019 first, then delete the `bin`,`obj`,`.vs` folder, if you can't find `.vs` folder, pls show the hide items in File explorer. At last, you can open your project with vs2019. If you still get the error, pls let us know.

Comment: Okay, I fix this problem but I don't know how. This is an interesting error, I restart VS2022 and this bug is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to search you the most persuasive blog or article for you.

Why my previous comment suggested deleting some folders and re-running the IDE is because we had this problem before too. I think what Rick Strahl's blog describes is our problem in this post. When we only compile, we should not encounter the above error.

[Fixing Visual Studio Intellisense Errors](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Aug/07/Fixing-Visual-Studio-Intellisense-Errors)

Of course, when you reopen it with VS2022, the problem will disappear.